# Regular Expression in Python to return complete character in a text file

Tags: python, regex

i want to search through a text file using python RegEx.. but instead of returning only my search string it should return the whole string it matched

```
python 3.7

   with open('movies.txt', 'w') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
        headers = ['Title',  'Link']
        csv_writer.writerow(headers)

        for post in posts:
            title = post.find('p').get_text()
            link = post.find('a')['href']
            csv_writer.writerow([title, link])

    with open('movies.txt') as m1, open('movies.csv', 'w') as m2:
        for line in m1:
            movies = re.findall('th+', line)
            m1.writelines(movie + '\n' for movie in movies)
```

if the texts in the textfile are: **What are you unstopable? unstoppable **
and i searched *'unst'* it should return *'unstopable'* and '*unstoppable'* in full

instead of returning only my search string it should return the whole string if matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to match alphanumeric characters, just append `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` to your pattern:

### Code

```python
import re

re.findall('unst[a-zA-Z0-9]*', 'What are you unstopable? unstoppable')
```

### Output

[image]

Hope this helps. Please, let me know if something went wrong.